# Updating checked radio button in two ways

Tags: html, jquery, forms, radio-button

Just like what you see in the picture, the default section is the default view that I have in a form. The appended view will get displayed based on the ajax request.

I'm trying to make the radio button to be able to reflect with each other when either from default or appended view get selected. Example like when I select `Yes` from **Default** then the **Appended View** also will auto update to `Yes`. Then from **Appended View** to select `No` it will reflect the **Default** to `No` as well.

[image: I have a default]

Please check on this link for my code and do testing
https://codepen.io/terrer-sandman/pen/WNwbPMv?editors=1010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```js
function autoSelect(id, value) {
  $('input[type=radio][data-id='+id+'][value='+value+']').click();
}

$('.can_claim_default').on('change', function(){
        autoSelect($(this).data('id'), $(this).val());
    })

$('#receipt-inline-view').on('change', 'input[name="can_claim"]', function(){
        autoSelect($(this).data('id'), $(this).val());
    })
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div style="padding: 15px;">

<!-- You can remove the "50002" from names and classes if you want -->

<p>Default</p>
<div>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" class="can_claim_default" name="can_claim_50002" data-id="50002" checked="" value="0">No Status
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" class="can_claim_default" name="can_claim_50002" data-id="50002" value="1">Yes
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" class="can_claim_default" name="can_claim_50002" data-id="50002" value="2">No
  </label>
</div>

<br /><br />

<p>Appended View</p>
<div id="receipt-inline-view">
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" class="can_claim_50002" name="can_claim" data-id="50002" checked="" value="0">No Status
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" class="can_claim_50002" name="can_claim" data-id="50002" value="1">Yes
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" class="can_claim_50002" name="can_claim" data-id="50002" value="2">No
  </label>
</div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Working great! Thank you so much!